# how to download file VIA wget while target path include Wildcards

Tags: bash, wildcard, wget, repo

here is elegant example how to download file and copy it to

```
/etc/yum.repo.d folder
```

example

```
REPOSITORY_SERVER=master_machine01
wget -nd -r -P /etc/yum.repos.d/  -A ".repo" "http://$REPOSITORY_SERVER/ambari/centos7/2.6.2.2-1/ambari.repo"
```

after above command ambari.repo file will copied to /etc/yum.repos.d/

note: the file amabri.rep path is

```
ls -ltr /var/www/html/ambari/centos7/2.6.2.2-1/ambari.repo
-rw-r--r-- 1 root users 304 Jun 11  2018 /var/www/html/ambari/centos7/2.6.2.2-1/ambari.repo
```

**so this is the simple case**

now what about path could be as ( with diff path's )

```
$REPOSITORY_SERVER/ambari/centos7/2.6.2.3-1/ambari.repo
```

or

```
$REPOSITORY_SERVER/ambari/centos7/2.6.2.2-4/ambari.repo
```

then how to use the cli with Wildcards

we try the following

```
wget -nd -r -P /etc/yum.repos.d/  -A ".repo" "http://$REPOSITORY_SERVER/ambari/centos7/*/ambari.repo"
```

but we get

```
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2021-11-28 18:40:07 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

or even with backslash

```
 wget -nd -r -P /etc/yum.repos.d/  -A ".repo" "http://$REPOSITORY_SERVER/ambari/centos7/\*/ambari.repo"
```

BUT WITH THE SAME ERROR

any idea how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how to use the cli with Wildcards

It is not possible to perform a glob expansion with HTTP protocol. These are very unrelated technologies.

> how to resolve this issue?

Devise and implement a method of getting the available files under certain path from an HTTP server. For example, contact the server administrator and ask him about it. Potentially, if the HTTP server supports serving a directory listing, recursively filter the listing to find all matching paths. Or find and query some other site that contains all the links and filter the obtained answer to extract all links, for example. Etc.

Comment: maybe other option by wget to view the folder name under - REPOSITORY_SERVER/ambari/centos7 , and then capture the folder name and set it in variable  ( example - http://$REPOSITORY_SERVER/ambari/centos7/$VERSION/ambari.repo

Comment: Yes, `if the HTTP server supports serving a directory listing, recursively filter the listing to find all matching paths`